# How to handle when user clicks on deny and checked the checkbox while asking for multiple permissions at a time in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

According to the [runtime permissions documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#coding) an app can check for runtime permissions and request permissions if it hasn't been granted already. So I was writing a program for handling run-time multiple  permissions at a time. I did it correctly but unable to handle when the user clicks on deny and checked the check box of "never ask again". In this case I want to open the permission intent as shown in image 2. when the user opens my application next time.

I am unable to detect the case when user checks the check box  "never ask again" and clicks on deny button.

[image]  [image]

Here is my code:

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("GPS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Read Contacts");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Write Contacts");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            showMessageOKCancel(message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }

    insertDummyContact();
}

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

and here is my callback method

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            {
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // All Permissions Granted
                insertDummyContact();
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not request for multiple permissions at the same time. This makes the user experience unpleasant. If the user clicks `'Do not ask again'`, since the checkbox is not shown the first time, it is probable that he doesn't want to use that feature of your application. But if he does try to use it, simply show a toast or snackbar that the feature can't be used since permission hasn't been granted by the user.

Programatically opening the permission screen isn't possible currently, and if you try, you'll get a security exception.

Comment: Then ask them in some interval. Use a handler  to achieve this.